# html.checkboxfor checked with pagedlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using pagedlist to display list which has nullable bool for status.Below is the code

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Status.HasValue, new { @onclick = "UpdateStatus(" + item.Id + ",this)" })
```

I am passing status value as bool but still all the checkboxes are checked by default even when the status is false. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

updated my checkbox to

```
@Html.CheckBox("Id", item.Status.HasValue ? item.Status.Value : false, new { @onclick = "UpdateStatus(" + item.Id + ",this)" })
```